# I get System.UnauthorizedAccessException while loading XML from disk

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, linq-to-xml

I am working on Windows 8 XAML/C# store app. I am trying to load XML from `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` to `XDocument` multiple times during the lifetime of the app. However, I receive `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` when I try to load the file. Here are my methods:

To add to XML:

```
private async void AddCategoryButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    XDocument CategoryListXDoc = await LoadXmlFromLocalFolderAsync("Categories.xml");
    CategoryListXDoc.Element("CategoryList").Add(
        new XElement("Category", new XAttribute("Id", Guid.NewGuid()), AddCategoryTextBox.Text));
    SaveXDocToLocalFolderAsync("Categories.xml", CategoryListXDoc);
}
```

Just for debugging purposes:

```
private async void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    XDocument TempXDoc = await LoadXmlFromLocalFolderAsync("Categories.xml");
    Debug.WriteLine(TempXDoc);
}
```

Load and Save methods:

```
private async Task<XDocument> LoadXmlFromLocalFolderAsync(string FileName)
{
    var LocalFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile CategoryListFile = await LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(FileName);
    var stream = await CategoryListFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync() as Stream;
    XDocument TempXDoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
    stream.Flush();
    return TempXDoc;            
}
private async void SaveXDocToLocalFolderAsync(string Filename, XDocument XDocToSave)
{
    var LocalFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile CategoryListFile = await LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(Filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    var stream = await CategoryListFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync() as Stream;
    XDocToSave.Save(stream);
    stream.Flush();
}
```

If I fire the `Click` events repeatedly, the exception is thrown. There's no specific scenario. Sometimes error occurs, sometimes it doesn't. Where am I going wrong? I'm pretty new with the `async` and `await` stuff.

Comment: So if you just navigate to the folder you are able to read the file?

Comment: whats your permission of that folder or file and have you started VS in administrator mode?

Comment: The `Click` events occur quickly one after another? It could be that maybe two `LoadXmlFromLocalFolderAsync` are executing in the same time or something to do with the fact that the file is held by a thread when another tries to use it.

Comment: @CoralDoe I'm thinking on the same lines. The error is sure to occur if I fire the events rapidly. Any solution to that?
@Larry Shouldn't be a problem. I'm using app's AppData folders recommended for sandboxed local and roaming storage. Moreover, it indeed is able to access the file sometimes.
@awright18 No offense, but did you miss the line with `StorageFile` creation?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if truly two threads are trying to access that file. Viewing the `Message` and the `StackTrace` of the exception should help.
Things like

```
  Message=Invalid cross-thread access.
 StackTrace:
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckThread()
```

should appears there.

A solution to this problem would be to use locks for the `LoadXmlFromLocalFolderAsync` method, in such way two threads could not open the file in the same time. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8544e2s(v=vs.100).aspx
Also a good suggestion for you is to always manage files in `try-catch-finally` blocks.

But this is getting a little dirty. The problem in interactive applications is not to allow users to click quickly buttons like crazy. You should disable button functionalities until the current one is finished. Imagine more complex operations occur at button click; this makes the system resources to be used unnecessary. It is not ok.
You should try to use methods that prevent double clicking like this:
http://tgynther.blogspot.ro/2011/07/aspnet-prevent-button-double-click.html

Comment: I don't think the disable button approach is working. (See comment on another answer.) About the `try-catch-finally` blocks: What do I put `catch` and `finally`? If I choose to show 'Sorry, something went wrong.' message, there would be too many of them. Is it a good practice to load XML to XDocument only at start and write to file periodically? Sorry, I'm really new to this.

Comment: You use `catch` to log error in viewable mode or try to solve the error (if you can). In finally you should close the file no matter what happened. If you write often to the file, it is better to open it once and used it at need, and close it when you know you won't need it no more. If you seldom use it, better open it each time.

Comment: I see that [this](http://goo.gl/k655z) person is using bindable methods to perform actions. Does this approach help my situation? I'll give `try-catch-finally` a try. Apparently, I need to re-architecture my app!