# Windows 8 Metro App - how to connect to MS Access via OleDb?

Tags: ms-access, windows-8, microsoft-metro, oledb

Can anyone tell how to connect windows 8 store(metro) app to MS Access using OleDb..? 
And i can't find reference called "System.Data.OleDb"..Any idea...
thanks in advance..

Comment: Check out the [SO discussion][1] about using databases in a Windows Store app.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660227/correct-way-to-use-databases-in-windows-8-and-windows-phone-8

Comment: @Zhiming Xue: thanks for the link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, sorry.  You can't directly connect to a SQL Server either though.  You *can* work with SQLLite files though.  Brilliant, eh?

Comment: thanks 4 your reply...is there any option other than sqlite...?

Comment: not really... microsoft would like you to stick your database on a server and expose it to your app through web services

Answer (score 0):

try adding the dll file to the project ,

like i added the dll file for sqllite for the reference and usage of sqllite. try adding dll.