# Pre-installed data on LongListSellector

Tags: c#, serialization, windows-phone-8, observablecollection, longlistselector

I've got an ObservableCollection which is binded to my LongListSelector.
User can add items to it by form in my app - all data saved in list are serialized.
I want to add few items to my app, that will be present after installation. User can delete and modify them, like any other items.
What is the best way to do that? I don't think that creating multiple objects in code is good idea.

Comment: Why would you think that multiple objext are a bad idea?

Comment: Because i need to add them to code in my application. I'm rather thinking about an external XML, or something...

Answer (score 0):

Local databases are what you need. They would even be helpful later of you plan to persist the changes user has made.

Windows Phone Silverlight has nice LINQ-to-SQL support with SQL server CE. Here's the information you'll need to implement databases: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

If you prefer app walkthrough, here it is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

You will need to deploy a reference database and copy it to isolated storage since you want user to have some data prepopulated. Here's a nice reference for such scenarios: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286411%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Edit: You can, of course, use external XML, but it has its fair share of problems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045504/i-get-system-unauthorizedaccessexception-while-loading-xml-from-disk).